# Remote access to C# Application (Win) best approach?

Tags: c#, admin

Would it be better to make some sort of internal Webserver and do it all over HTTP or to make the app to read remote files ? .. can't explain it better than this right now.

Got any good link's about this, please post :)

Comment: please explain better. Do you want to control a windows forms application which runs on another machine with its UI as well, from a remote computer? Do you have full control on the source code and can you make changes? Can you also make it again web based? :D

Comment: What's the required functionality for this app? The answer to this heavily depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well i have 100% control of the source, since it's my own project.

The app is an audio player and are ment to be running in a bar on a touch screen system. 

What i want is the ability to make playlists from local files on the  player PC and have the posibility to upload from client PC's.. 

Make any sence at all ? hehe sorry, not good at this ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As michalczerwinski said, it's better to use some kind of network-based interface.

If you don't want to use IIS, you can make self-hosted application with WCF service:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Using remote files to stear the external application is not the best approach: it will introduce the delay and it's far from being efficient. Any network-based interface would be better. I would go with Remoting or WCF to host some simple interfaces, it might be via HTTP.